# Transact-SQL stored procedure with conditional "AND" logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm working on a stored procedure that is used to filter a grid based on criteria entered by the user.  Among the possible criteria they may choose to see transactions that were done between a certain begin and end date.  I pass 4 input parameters to the proc - @ClientKey, the client requesting the info, @FilterBy (this is the selected value from a dropdown list in ASP.NET, and essentially tells the proc whether the user is selecting to filter by name, address, date, etc.  In this case the @FilterBy value for date is 5), @Value1, which in this instance would be the begin date, and @Value2, which in this instance would be the end date.

In pseudo-code, what I want is:

SELECT ABunchOfColumns
FROM SomeJoinedTables
WHERE SomeCriteria
AND CASE @FilterBy
WHEN 5 THEN d.TransactionTime >= CAST(@Value1 AS Date) AND d.TransactionTime <= CAST(@Value2 AS Date)

Below is the full query.  I hope that someone who is more savvy than me with SQL can sort out what I'm trying to do and offer a solution.

Thanks in advance!

```
@ClientKey  int,
@FilterBy   int,
@Value1 varchar(150),
@Value2 varchar(150)
```

AS
BEGIN

```
SELECT d.pKey AS PaymentKey, d.CaseKey, d.InvoiceID, d.AuthorizationCode, d.TransactionID, d.PaymentType, d.Amount, d.ExpirationDate, d.CardType, d.BankName, d.AccountNumber, 
    d.AccountType, c.Name, c.Address1, c.City, c.State, c.Zip, cs.PAmount, cs.TranCode, cs.TranDate, cs.[Desc] AS PaymentDescription, cc.[Desc] AS ChargeCodeDescription,
    d.TransactionTime, a.Name AS AssociationName, d.PaymentType, c.ClientPaymentID
FROM DebtorPayment d INNER JOIN Cases c
    ON d.CaseKey = c.pKey
    AND d.ClientKey = c.ClientKey
INNER JOIN CaseSumm cs
    ON d.CaseKey = cs.CaseKey
    AND d.pKey = cs.Batch
    AND d.ClientKey = cs.ClientKey
INNER JOIN ChargeCodes cc
    ON c.ClientKey = cc.ClientKey
    AND cs.TranCode = cc.RefNum
INNER JOIN AssnCtrl a
    ON c.AssnKey = a.pKey
WHERE c.ClientKey = @ClientKey
AND d.AmountAllocated > 0
AND d.TransactionStatus = 'Successful' 
AND c.Address1 LIKE CASE
    WHEN @FilterBy = 1 THEN '%' + @Value1 + '%'
    ELSE c.Address1
    END
AND d.Amount = CASE
    WHEN @FilterBy = 2 THEN @Value1
    ELSE d.Amount
    END  
AND a.pKey = CASE
    WHEN @FilterBy = 3 THEN CAST(@Value1 AS INT)
    ELSE a.pKey
    END
AND c.ClientPaymentID = CASE
    WHEN @FilterBy = 4 THEN @Value1
    ELSE c.ClientPaymentID
    END 
<ProblemArea>
AND CASE @FilterBy
        WHEN 5 THEN d.TransactionTime >= CAST(@Value1 AS Date) AND d.TransactionTime <= CAST(@Value2 AS Date)
    END
</ProblemArea>
AND c.LName LIKE CASE
    WHEN @FilterBy = 6 THEN '%' + @Value1 + '%'
    ELSE c.LName
    END
ORDER BY d.TransactionTime DESC
```

END

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CASE 
    WHEN @FilterBy = 5 AND d.TransactionTime >= CAST(@Value1 AS DATE) 
    AND d.TransactionTime <= CAST(@Value2 AS DATE) THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
END = 1
```

Comment: or..

CASE 
    WHEN @FilterBy = 5 AND d.TransactionTime BETWEEN CAST(@Value1 AS DATE) 
    AND CAST(@Value2 AS DATE) THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END = 1

Works the same, but the between makes the code more readable.  That just a personal preference, there is no difference in execution.

Comment: Actually I only tested this briefly before having to complete another system enhancement.  Now that I'm back on this, it seems that the proc is not returning any rows for and @FilterBy value other than 5.  Not sure why.

Comment: for *any @FilterBy value other than 5.

Comment: @Mike I only focused in the "problem area" part of your where. It seems that you need to use `AND ((First @FilterBy) OR (Second @FilterBy) OR ....)`. In any case, I didn't review everyone of those filters

Comment: Thanks Lamak - understand the focused scope.  No joy yet, but still trying.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the following?
You might find this [link](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) useful too.
Haven't tested the code, just proposing idea - and writing code like this has always felt "wrong" to me - perhaps someone could offer better.

```
CREATE PROC MyProc

    @ClientKey  int,
    @FilterBy   int,
    @Value1 varchar(150),
    @Value2 varchar(150)
--  NB WITH RECOMPILE, see link (above)
WITH RECOMPILE AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM ...
    WHERE 
        Col1    =   CASE 
                        WHEN @FilterBy = 1 THEN @Value1
                        ELSE Col1
                    END
    AND
        1       =   CASE
                        WHEN @FilterBy = 2 AND Col2 > @Value1 AND Col3 < @Value2        THEN 1
                        WHEN @FilterBy = 2 AND NOT (Col2 > @Value1 AND Col3 < @Value2)  THEN 0
                        ELSE 1
                    END 
END
```